# How do I subtract a percentage from a number in a string?

Tags: javascript

```
var valueInString = "2383";
```

How do I subtract 35% from number and put it back in the variable?

```
valueInString = valueInString - 35%
```

Something like the above?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to subtract 35% of `valueInString` from `valueInString`. So it is just some basic math.

```
var valueInString = "2383";
var num = parseFloat(valueInString);
var val = num - (num * .35);
console.log(val);
```

Comment: And @rynah's answer is cleaner above, just showing the math in a different way.

Comment: What if we want to subtract 6.25%? 
I tried .6.25 << was pretty stupid.

Answer (score 14):

Math:

```
valueInString = valueInString * (1 - 0.35);
```

Shorter:

```
valueInString *= 1 - 0.35;
```

Comment: And even more short `valueInString *= 0.65` :)

Comment: Worth noting that the multiplication operator coerces strings to  numbers, but in the same situation, "+" will be considered a concatenation operator and coerce numbers to strings so the result of `valueInString + (1 - 0.35)` will be `23830.65`.

Comment: whoops...lol Off by one error. Looks like someone else got the comment.

Answer (score 3):

A nice little utility function for this would be:

```
const percentageOff = (
  price: number,
  percentageValue: number
): number => {
  return price * (1 - percentageValue / 100)
}

percentageOff(100, 50); // Output: 50
```

Answer (score -1):

```
valueInString = valueInString - ((valueInString * 35) / 100);
```

Comment: This is 35% of valueInString, **not** valueInString - 35% (which would be `0.65 * valueInString`.